# Why no Internet with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, internet

Ubuntu 17.10 can use the Internet with its Live cd. Firefox works fine.
Ubuntu 18.04 cannot use the Internet with its Live cd. Firefox doesn't connect.
They can connect to their access point, but will not go any further to the Internet.
Firefox and downloading repositories do not work. 
Why and how to fix?

Comment: Seems unlikely that all Ubuntu 18.04 Live CD's are unable to connect to the internet.  Can you give some more details on your situation?

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic here (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as its not Ubuntu nor an official flavor of Ubuntu. I'm assuming you are using DHCP for both, have you checked it works correctly. By connecting to your access point I assume you could `ping` to your 'access-point'.  If you tried pinging to a external address (eg. 8.8.8.8 being google's dns) does that work??  If you don't provide actual ip addresses, but use human-names eg. google.com I assume you mean that fails. Please be specific?  `ip addr` will show your ip address; `ip route` will show basic routing info.

Comment: 17.10,1 Can access wireless access points and Internet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: No blocks, soft or hard.